# Valid JavaScript Producing an Invalid Operation

Tags: jquery, html, css, hide, jsfiddle

I'm building a website that utilizes JavaScript - more specifically jQuery - but the code will not properly run.

I have an element that I'm trying to hide for later exposure in a sliding format.

Here's the code because StackOverflow won't let me post without including some code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("itemStudentsLink").hide();
    $("#PHHS").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#PHHS").fadeTo("slow", 0.7); 
    });
    $("slH").mouseenter(function(){
       $("itemStudentsLink").show("slow"); 
    });
    $(".itemStudentsLink").mouseenter(function(){
       $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1.0); 
    });
    $(".itemStudentsLink").mouseleave(function(){
       $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.5); 
    });
    $( "#PHHS" ).click(function() {
        $("#PHHS, #notifier").toggle( "fold" );
    });
    $( "#PHHS" ).mouseenter(function() {
        $("#notifier").removeClass("notifierConceal").addClass("notifierReveal");
        $("#notifier").fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
  });
});
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zulfe/mKYaL/) for a visual, full reference.
I can't seem to figure out why the box elements won't properly hide.

Comment: You're missing the `.` before `.itemStudnetsLink`.

Comment: Please describe what one should do in the jsFiddle and what is not happening that you expect.

Comment: @jfriend00 He said: "the box elements won't properly hide".

Comment: @Barmar - and what are "box elements".  I don't know what I'm supposed to do in the jsFiddle and what I'm supposed to see.  A simple set of steps to reproduce the problem would attract a lot better answers.

Comment: They're the red boxes, which are supposed to be hidden by the `hide()` call at the beginning of the code, and then shown by the `mouseEnter` handler. If you read the code, it's obvious what he's trying to do, and he just has some syntax problems.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some of the `.` and `#` prefixes for classes and IDs.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".itemStudentsLink").hide(); // <-- here
    $("#PHHS").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#PHHS").fadeTo("slow", 0.7); 
    });
    $("#slH").mouseenter(function(){ // <-- here
       $(".itemStudentsLink").show("slow");  // <-- here
    });
    $(".itemStudentsLink").mouseenter(function(){
       $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1.0); 
    });
    $(".itemStudentsLink").mouseleave(function(){
       $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.5); 
    });
    $( "#PHHS" ).click(function() {
        $("#PHHS, #notifier").toggle( "fold" );
    });
    $( "#PHHS" ).mouseenter(function() {
        $("#notifier").removeClass("notifierConceal").addClass("notifierReveal");
        $("#notifier").fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
  });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/mKYaL/6/)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

I forgot to add the ID or Class identifiers...

Noob failures.

Comment: You figured it out? I told you in the first comment!